# Set rails default version while using rvm for version management

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I have installed  rails using rvm.When I use this command `rvm gemset list` I get the following output.

```
gemsets for ruby-2.1.1 (found in /home/aspire9/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1)
=> (default)
   global
   rails-4.0
   rails-4.0.0
```

Now to use rails command I have to use `rvm gemset use rails-4.0.0` whenever I open a new terminal.
Is there any way to set rails-4.0.0 as default so I don't have to fire `rvm gemset use rails-4.0.0` everytime I open my terminal

I am using linux mint and I have even added rails-4.0.0 into environment path but Somehow it is not working.

I have also tried using rvm gemset use rails-4.0.0 --default that too didn't worked

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully  overcame with the following command:

```
rvm use 2.1.1@rails-4.0.0
```

rvm use **your-ruby-version**@**your-rails-version-alias**

Hope this helps any other beginners because it's not mentioned in rvm documentaion.